# Remove duplicate from foreach php

Tags: php, mysql

I have already tried array_unique but not getting the desired results.

Here is the db structure:

[image]

Here is what i have tried but getting the same 'user 1' two times it should be one .

```
$stmt = $db_con->query("SELECT sender,recipient, content, sending_time
FROM messages AS sender
WHERE (sender='admin' OR recipient='admin')
GROUP BY sender,recipient
ORDER BY sending_time DESC
");

$stmt->execute();
foreach ($stmt as $key => $value) {

    if ($value['sender'] == 'admin') {
        $my = $value['recipient'];
    } else if ($value['recipient'] == 'admin') {
        $my = $value['sender'];
    } else {
        $my = $value['sender'];
    }
    if (!in_array($my, explode(' ', $my))) {
        echo '<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="list-group-item p10 b0 b-rad-0">
                    <div class="online-users pull-left mr5">
                        <img src="../uploads/userprofile/default/avatar.jpg" onerror="this.onerror=null;imgDefault(this);" alt="avatar" class="online-users-img">
                        <span title="online"></span>
                    </div>
                    <strong class="text-primary h4 mb2">' . $my . '<small class="pull-right">OCT 23</small></strong>
                    <div><small class="text-muted">asdasdajkasdhjgjhgjhgjhgjghjgjgggggggggggggsdfsdf...</small></div>
                </a>';

    }
}
```

here is the data from db using the following:

```
$sddsf = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
print_r($sddsf);

Array ( [0] => Array (
        [sender] => 2224 
        [recipient] => admin
        [content] => sad
        [sending_time] => 1536513903 ) 
    [1] => Array (
        [sender] => admin 
        [recipient] => user1 
        [content] => def 
        [sending_time] => 1536513874 ) 
    [2] => Array (
        [sender] => user1 
        [recipient] => admin 
        [content] => abc 
        [sending_time] => 1536513532 ) ))
```

Comment: You need to tell us what consitutes "unique". Reading your code, it looks like it might be the sender but that seems a bit weird. There is a lot wrong with this code. It looks as if you intended to use $sddsf to track which records you wrote out - but you never assign any values to the array.

Comment: @symcbean thanks for pointing that out basically i am getting two 'user1' and i want to show only one of them (does 't matter which one ) .I have updated the code please take a look.

Comment: The problem is if i place to remove 'user1' it removes all of the results related with user1 but on placing $my1 it removes all

Comment: You'll also make it a lot easier for people to help you if you use a recognisable code style. PSR-2 for preference.

Answer (score 0):

```
//Find duplicates 

$arr_data = array( 
    'one', 
    'two', 
    'Three', 
    'Four', 
    'Five', 
    'Six', 
    'Seven', 
    'Eight', 
    'Nine' 
);
$unique_data = array_unique($arr_data); 
$dup= array_diff_key( $arr_data, $unique_data); 
array_count_values($dup);
```